# PHP views relate controllers

Tags: php, templates, yii, yii-routing

I would like to implement controllers that connect to any specific views like MVC does. I'm **not** using any framework that provided in PHP.

So, I need some guide and advice on doing it.

I have some controllers and views. For my views,i would like to just output my data only. 
My concern now is how my function (like `create()` ) in controllers, can get all the `$_POST['params']` that users input data in my `views/create.php`, and create a new Model in the `create()` controllers's function.

So,right now, i'm thinking to do in this way, I will create **MyViews** class in my controllers folder. The purpose is loading the specific views and get all the `$_POST` params into an object. Then, every controllers like **Users_controllers**, will create **MyViews**. In the function of **Users_controllers**, like `create()`, `destroy()`, I might use the function in **MyViews** to load specific views to load the object.

I found a source that load views

```
<?php
class MyView {
protected $template_dir = 'templates/';
protected $vars = array();
public function __construct($template_dir = null) {
    if ($template_dir !== null) {
        // Check here whether this directory really exists
        $this->template_dir = $template_dir;
    }
}
public function render($template_file) {
    if (file_exists($this->template_dir.$template_file)) {
        include $this->template_dir.$template_file;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('no template file ' . $template_file . ' present in     directory ' . $this->template_dir);
    }
}
public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->vars[$name] = $value;
}
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->vars[$name];
}
} ?>
```

hmm,I have no idea How I can detect the _POST params

```
    if(isset($_POST['Post']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Post'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }
```

this is the Yii framework I observed. How could I detect params whether is `$_POST` or `$_GET` after load a specific views.

Any guidance and advice to archive my tasks?

Comment: Try `if(count($_POST) > 0) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>**Unrelared to question** 
> You have one major problem: your ability to express what mean is extremely limited. The question, which you asked, was actually unrelated to your problem.</sub>

From what I gather, you need to detect of user made a `POST` or `GET` request. Do detect it directly you can check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, but checking it withing controller might be quite bothersome. You will end up with a lot of controller's methods which behave differently based on request method.

Since you are not using any of popular frameworks, is would recommend for you to instead delegate this decision to the routing mechanism.

A pretty good way to handle this, in my opinion, is to prefix the controller's method names with the request method: `postLogin()`, `getArticles()` etc. You can find few additional example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855644/727208). If there is a `POST` request, it *will* have something in `$_POST` array.

> <sub>What are calling "views" are actually templates. If you read [this article](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html), you will notice, that the code there is actually an improved version of your `MyView`. Views are not templates. Views are instances which contain presentation logic and manipulate multiple templates.</sub>

<sub>**P.S.** If you are exploring MVC and MVC-inspired patterns in relation to PHP, you might find [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) useful.</sub>